# Condition on Custom Tab in Customer Account page

Tags: customtab, condition

[image]

**app\code\companyname\modulename\view\frontend\layout\default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Codility_Customers::css/firstfile.css" media="all and (min-width: 1px)"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="seller-dashboard-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">seller/customer/index</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Link 1</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">800</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLinkInterface" name="seller-dashboard-myorder">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">seller/customer/orders</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Link 2</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">700</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

   </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now I want to hid `Link 1` or `Link-2` on some condition. e.g I will check on specific customer group

```
if(customergroup=="General"){
// then show Tabs otherwise Tabs will not show
}
```

anyone guide me how put condition here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom module or existing your any custom module will add this files.

Create a custom file

> Vendor\Module_name\Model\Config\Source\Sections

```
    <?php
            namespace Vendor\Module_name\Model\Config\Source;

            use Magento\Framework\App\Utility\Files;
            use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;
            use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links;

            class Sections implements ArrayInterface
            {
                /** @var Files  */
                protected $utilityFiles;

                protected $links;

                protected $list = [];

                public function __construct(
                    Files $utilityFiles,
                    Links $links
                ) {
                    $this->utilityFiles = $utilityFiles;
                    $this->links = $links;
                }
                /**
                 * @return array
                 */
                public function toOptionArray()
                {
                    return $this->getSections();
                }

                /**
                 * @return array
                 */
                public function getSections()
                {
                    $fileList = $this->utilityFiles->getLayoutFiles(['area_name' => 'frontend'], false);

                    foreach ($fileList as $configFile) {
                        if (strpos($configFile, 'customer_account.xml') !== false) {
                            $configXml = simplexml_load_file($configFile);
                            $this->processXmlElement($configXml);
                        }
                    }

                    return $this->list;
                }

                /**
                 * @param $configXml
                 */
                protected function processXmlElement($configXml)
                {
                    if ($referenceBlocks = $configXml->body->referenceBlock) {
                        foreach ($referenceBlocks as $referenceBlock) {
                            if (!empty($referenceBlock->xpath('block/arguments/argument[@name="label"]'))) {
                                $this->updateReferenceBlockList($referenceBlock);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (isset($configXml->body->referenceContainer) && isset($configXml->body->referenceContainer->block)) {
                        if (isset($configXml->body->referenceContainer->block->block)
                            && isset($configXml->body->referenceContainer->block->block->block)
                        ) {
                            $referenceContainerBlocks = $configXml->body->referenceContainer->block->block->block;

                            for ($count = 0; $count < count($referenceContainerBlocks); $count++) {
                                if (!empty($referenceContainerBlocks[$count]->xpath('arguments/argument[@name="label"]'))) {
                                    $this->updateReferenceContainerList($referenceContainerBlocks, $count);
                                }
                            }
                        } elseif (isset($configXml->body->referenceContainer->block->block)) {
                            $referenceContainerBlocks = $configXml->body->referenceContainer->block->block;

                            for ($count = 0; $count < count($referenceContainerBlocks); $count++) {
                                if (!empty($referenceContainerBlocks[$count]->xpath('arguments/argument[@name="label"]'))) {
                                    $this->updateReferenceContainerList($referenceContainerBlocks, $count);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * @param $rcb
                 * @param $count
                 */
                protected function updateReferenceContainerList($rcb, $count)
                {
                    $this->list[(string) $rcb[$count]['name']] = [
                        'value' => (string) $rcb[$count]['name'],
                        'label' => (string) $rcb[$count]->xpath('arguments/argument[@name="label"]')[0],
                        'path' => (string) $rcb[$count]->xpath('arguments/argument[@name="path"]')[0]
                    ];
                }

                /**
                 * @param $rb
                 */
                protected function updateReferenceBlockList($rb)
                {
                    $this->list[(string) $rb->block['name']] = [
                        'value' => (string) $rb->block['name'],
                        'label' => (string) $rb->xpath('block/arguments/argument[@name="label"]')[0],
                        'path' => (string) $rb->xpath('block/arguments/argument[@name="path"]')[0]

                    ];
                }
            }
```

overide this file in your custom theme

> vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\collapsible.phtml

```
  <?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$customerLinks = $objectManager->get("Vendor\Module_name\Model\Config\Source\Sections")->toOptionArray();

                    //echo "<pre>";print_r($customerLinks);
                    $customerSession = $objectManager->create("Magento\Customer\Model\Session");

                    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

                    $baseUrl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);

                    ?>
                    <div class="block <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBlockCss() ?>">
                        <div class="title <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBlockCss() ?>-title" data-mage-init='{"toggleAdvanced": {"toggleContainers": "#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBlockCss() ?>", "selectorsToggleClass": "active"}}'>
                            <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __($block->getBlockTitle()) ?></strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBlockCss() ?>-content" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBlockCss() ?>">
                        <?php if($block->getBlockCss() == 'block-collapsible-nav' && $customerSession->isLoggedIn()){
                                ?>
                                <ul class="nav items">
                                <?php foreach ($customerLinks as $links) { 
                                    if($customerSession->getCustomerGroupId() == 1 && $links['label'] == 'My Product Reviews'){
                                        //dont show for these customer product reviews
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    $url =  $baseUrl.$links['path']; ?>
                                    <li class="nav item"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><?php echo $links['label']; ?></a></li>
                                <?php } ?>
                                </ul>
                        <?php   }
                        else { ?>
                            <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Try this as per your customised it.

Comment: little work but very lengthy  code  .
i try it

Comment: @HaFizUmer hahahaha yes bro..but cool

Comment: i don't add tab from `customer_account.xml` . in use `referenceBlock` in `default.xml`

Comment: Brother you must add in customer_account.xml

Comment: Okay Brother let me try wait please :)

Comment: it work perfectly .
But i don't want to override 'vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\collapsible.phtml' file in custom theme.

Can this file override in custom_module ?

Comment: <referenceBlock name="block-name">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">MyCustom_Module::path/to/my/file.phtml </argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>

Answer (score 1):

Create two separate block classes for each link. In those classes override `_toHtml()` method and check for customer's group. If the customer belongs to desired group, then `return parent::_toHtml();` else `return '';`

Comment: can you explain more ? if you update your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new class: **VendorName\Customer\Block\Account\LinkUnderCondition.php**

   ```
   namespace VendorName\Customer\Block\Account;

   use Magento\Customer\Block\Account\SortLink;
   use Magento\Framework\App\DefaultPathInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

   class LinkUnderCondition extends SortLink
   {
       public function __construct(
           Context $context,
           DefaultPathInterface $defaultPath,
           array $data = [],
       ) {
           // you can add here more dependencies if needed
           parent::__construct($context, $defaultPath, $data);
       }

       public function _toHtml()
       {
           if(true) { // change to your needed condition
               return parent::_toHtml();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

---

2. Change the block classes for the custom links accordingly in your layout xml files. Example result:

```
<block class="VendorName\Customer\Block\Account\LinkUnderCondition" name="seller-dashboard-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">seller/customer/index</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Link 1</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">800</argument>
            </arguments>
</block>
```